# Combine latitude, longitude and value ascii files

Tags: raster, ascii

I have three ascii files of latitude, longitude and value. How to combine these three ascii files into a single raster of GTiff format?

Comment: Are the points in the ascii files at the grid positions or at irregular positions? gdal_grid can interpolate from skattered points, you can use csv (ascii) files. See  http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html and http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html

Comment: first you should get one file from these three. If you are in a unix system or can use msys for windows, you could use the join command. It will merge files to columns: http://www.albany.edu/~ig4895/join.htm
second you can choose if you interpolate irregular points to a grid or directly build a grid from regular points. As Zoltan said, gdal hat commandline tools for both.

Comment: The points are at grid position no need of interpolation